# Javascript array not returning the correct length

Tags: javascript

This is probably something really stupid but for the life of me i can't see it.

I have code that fills an array with strings and ii then want to loop through the array and add the values to as options in a select control. But for some reason when i call the length property it returns 0, but if i use console.dir to display the array in the console it has data in it.

here's the code:

```
var sectors = new Array();
// code to add values 
$.getJSON("get/tech_info.php", {uid:json.uid}, function(data){

    $.each(data, function(i, json){
        if($.inArray(json.area, sectors) == -1)
        {
            sectors[sectors.length] = json.area;
        }
    });
});


console.dir(sectors);

var sec = "#mainSectors" + count;
console.log(sectors.length); // returning 0
for ( var i=0; i != sectors.length; i++ ){

    console.log("bla bla bla");
    $(sec).append(
        $("<option></option>").html(sectors[i])
    );
}
```

Here's the cosole.dir data which you can see has data:

```
//secotrs
Array[0]
0: "Industrial"
1: "Commercial"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you actually use `console.dir`? And the code where you add values?

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in `// code to add values goes here //`.

Comment: i see that your array is multidimentional

Comment: if i go sectors[0].length it throws an error, it's just the way console.dir displays the data

Comment: What is the error? If `sectors[0] = "Industrial"`, then `sectors[0].length` should show `10` (the length of the string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making an Ajax call. Ajax is **asynchronous**! The code after the call (the `for` loop) is run **before** the callback executed (and the array is populated).

Put all the code that depends on `sectors` in the callback:

```
var sectors = [];

$.getJSON("get/tech_info.php", {uid:json.uid}, function(data){

    $.each(data, function(i, json){
        if($.inArray(json.area, sectors) == -1)
        {
            sectors.push(json.area);
        }
    });

    var sec = "#mainSectors" + count;
    console.log(sectors.length); //
    for ( var i=0; i != sectors.length; i++ ){

        console.log("bla bla bla");
        $(sec).append(
            $("<option></option>").html(sectors[i])
        );
    }

});
```

---

**Update:**

Regarding the output of `console.dir`: It is as I assumed. The properties of the object are fetched when you expand the entry in the console, not when you make the call.

Example:

```
> a = [];
  []
> console.dir(a)
  ▸ Array[0]
    undefined
> a.push(5)
  1
```

When I now click the marker next to `Array[0]`, I get:

```
▾ Array[0]
   0: 5
   length: 1
  ▸ __proto__: Array[0]
```

where one would expect that it does **not** show `0: 5` as it was added later (after the `console.dir` call).

Comment: but i'm calling console.dir before i try to loop through the array, and the console.dir has data.

Comment: @MattBH: I'm not sure about that one. But you can see that it prints `Array[0]` where it should be `Array[2]`. Fact is that the for loop will be run before the response is received.

Comment: if you look a bit further down you can see the length property is = 2

Comment: @Matt: I know. Maybe the values are fetched by the time you click on that little marker to list the properties of the object and not when you actually call `console.dir`. And when you click it, the Ajax call most likely already returned.

Comment: I don't know how or why but you are right. I was wrong. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

You are showing the `length` property (with `console.log`) *before* something is added to the array, so I suppose 0 is the right length there. After that, you are looping an empty array.

Furthermore, should sectors have `length`, then `for ( var i=0; i != sectors.length; i++ )` can run endless, because it skips `i` when it's not sectors.length and moves on. Use `i<sectors.length`.

Comment: i've pasted the code to add the values into the question.But it's not even getting into the for loop

Comment: Ok, I see you've got an answer. I was too occupied with work to look further, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose for this line `sectors[sectors.length] = json.area;` *sectors* is out of the scope `var sectors = new Array();` should be in the main scope outside any function

Comment: As long as `sectors` is in the same or a higher scope it is fine.

Comment: that's a copy paste of the code, sectors is declared and initialized before the function call

Comment: however Felix Kling got the answer, i thought it might be out of scope but it is actually out of synch.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the following:

```
  if($.inArray(json.area, sectors) == -1)
```

be

```
  if($.inArray(json.area, sectors) != -1)
```