# Javascript array length when reading a file

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am loading some files form my server via XMLHttpRequest. The loaded files should then be pushed onto an Array object so that I can process them. Here is my code:

```
var fileList = [];

angular.forEach(images, function(image, key) {

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', '/img/listings/' + image.dir + '/' + image.name, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.send();

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
        alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found

    } else {
        var blob = new File([this.response], {type: 'image/png'}); 
        fileList[0] = blob; 
    }

};

console.log(fileList);
console.log(fileList.length);
```

The result of the console log is:

```
[]
0: File {name: "[object Object]", lastModified: 1569449982337, lastModifiedDate: Wed Sep 25 2019 23:19:42 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 77928, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But the length is 0. Why is the length 0 when it has content.

Comment: I believe `fileList[0] = blob;` should be `fileList.push(blob);`

Comment: Take a look here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355382/javascript-array-not-returning-the-correct-length

Simply said it calculate length before asynchronous call is finished.

Comment: @Tigger I had already tried push - propblem remains: length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few little things happening.

First, change this code:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
        alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found

    } else {
        var blob = new File([this.response], {type: 'image/png'}); 
        fileList[0] = blob; 
    }
};
console.log(fileList);
console.log(fileList.length);
```

to

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status != 200) { // analyze HTTP status of the response
        alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`); // e.g. 404: Not Found

    } else {
        var blob = new File([this.response], {type: 'image/png'}); 
        // You wanted to add to the array.
        // Using fileList[0] will overwrite the 0 element/object
        fileList.push(blob);
    }
   //console.log(fileList);
   console.log(fileList.length);
};
```

And the reason why?

Placing the `console.log` outside of the AJAX will not work as the AJAX will work on a different thread in the background but the `console.log` call will be run on main thread. See [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for a lot more detail.

The other thing you are doing is overwriting your `0` index element of `fileList` with the `fileList[0] = blob;`. You will need to change that to `fileList.push(blob);` to add the object to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `console.log` happens at a different time from when you actually push the blob in your array.

What I mean is that `console.log(fileList)` receives a reference to the array, which means it will show the *current value* of the array. So, the value is after you got the file.

However, `console.log(fileList.length)` obtains the length of the array *before* you are done obtaining the file. It is not the current value and the one at the time of the `console.log`. I believe it is because the `Number` is passed by value and not by reference.

#### Edit:

For example, if you `log` your length after this line:
`fileList[0] = blob;`
it will show the current length.