# Different Array(s) in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Why does Chrome Dev Tools put a "(3)" in front of the fruit array, but not the array of years?

[image]

The first one is the result of a fetch like so:

```
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/damagequery')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      data.forEach(element => {
          console.log(element[""][1])
          damageCount.push(element[""][0])
          year.push(element[""][1].toString())
        //   [0][""]
        // [0][""][0]
      });
  });
```

and the second is just a test like this:

```
let fruit = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
```

Comment: Define "difference".

Comment: well, you see how the dev tools put a "(3)" in front of the fruit array, but not the year. Why is that?

Comment: That's the length of the array.

Comment: right, but why is there not a "(6)" in front of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is very simple, `year` array is logged to the console before it is filled. You used `fetch` which is asynchronous, so it is called after `console.log(year)`, but due to references in JS, the array is 'refreshed' after you click on it in console.

Similar situation below:

```
let year = [];
let fruit = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges'];

setTimeout(function() {
    const response = ["2000", "2016", "2017"];

    response.forEach(element => {
        year.push(element);
    });
}, 500);

console.log(year);
console.log(fruit);
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yzucwp5b/

Comment: Is this the same reason for when the console tells me:  `0: (27) [empty × 24, Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]`  and when I click on it there are no empty arrays?

Comment: Hi @close, I am not sure, could you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how. I am developing a userscript and this console message is bothering me.

Comment: You should try to extract the problem and make a working example with the related code in jsfiddle. Without that, it is really hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

JS does array equality comparing the references, which means even if your arrays contain the same elements they won't be equal because they live at different memory addresses.

If you want to compare two arrays I would recommend using lodash. See an example here:

[Using lodash to compare jagged arrays (items existence without order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951293/using-lodash-to-compare-jagged-arrays-items-existence-without-order)

If you don't want to use lodash, you'll need to define your own logic:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [1, 2, 3];
const areEqual = a.length === b.lenght && a.every((elem, index) => elem === b[index]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I edited my question to be more direct. I know that the contents of these two arrays are not the same because they're not supposed to be, I am more interested in why dev tools is displaying them differently.

Comment: Please see this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120547/array-list-length-is-zero-but-array-is-not-empty

Answer (score 0):

this question seems to be related to this one which has a very detailed response.

[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I edited my question to be more direct. I know that the contents of these two arrays are not the same because they're not supposed to be, I am more interested in why dev tools is displaying them differently.

Comment: Take a look at this response, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355382/javascript-array-not-returning-the-correct-length "Regarding the output of console.dir: It is as I assumed. The properties of the object are fetched when you expand the entry in the console, not when you make the call." Did you use console.dir to create those logs?